Is null safety support now (more or less) mandatory for dart
I've found that Dart support for swagger-codegen has suffered bitrot. The output doesn't work with modern projects as its not null-safe.
I was about to work on a patch. However, I don't know if null-safety more or less mandatory now. Should code generators need to support both null-safe and non-null-safe dart as separate language variants?

null safety is built into any version of dart 2.12 or higher. If you have a recent version of the dart compiler, it doesn't support setting the version lower than 2.12 anymore. So I would say, no, there isn't much point supporting a non-null safe version.

Code generators should not support both.  If anyone needs to generate code for legacy, non-null-safe Dart, then their projects should depend on an older version of the generator.

Yes, sound null safety is now mandatory from Dart 3.
From Sound null safety on Dart's website, it says:

Dart 3 has built-in sound null safety. Dart 3 prevents code without it
from running.

